# Big Sur "sleep" does not lock screen (when slept via keyboard shortcut)

Tags: security, sleep-wake, big-sur, screen-lock

**EDIT: corrected keyboard shortcut to say ⏻ rather than ⏏**

I put my computer to sleep using <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>opt</kbd>+<kbd>⏻</kbd> whenever I leave my desk.
For years, this has reliably locked the screen of the computer.

But ever since I upgraded to macOS 11 Big Sur: sleeping the computer does **not** lock the screen. I return to my computer later (minutes or hours), wake it up with the keyboard, and find that the computer is ready-to-use; no lock screen is presented.

Specifically, sleeping via keyboard shortcut does not lock it. Whereas sleeping by selecting "Sleep" with the mouse in the Apple menu seems to work.

My settings are the same as always:

[image: Require password immediately after sleep begins]

I'm using a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15" Mid-2014) on 11.1 Big Sur.

I have all the latest updates:

[image]

Is anybody else experiencing this? For my part, this is a security regression that has reduced my trust in macOS.

Comment: What Mac model specifically? I didn't think anything old enough to have an Eject button could run Big Sur.

Comment: @Tetsujin https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MQ052LL/A/magic-keyboard-with-numeric-keypad-us-english-silver. I can't reproduce the problem though, sleeping via keyboard leads to the lock screen on wake-up.

Comment: Did you try to toggle the security setting (disable it, quit System Preferences, then enable it again)?

Comment: @nohillside I had tried toggling the security setting, but I hadn't tried quitting System Preferences in-between toggles. that actually appears to have fixed it! would you like to submit that as an answer? I don't know whether this will fix it permanently; if the problem comes back I would need to un-mark as answer.

Comment: @Tetsujin ah, if I press on the internal keyboard, then the shortcut is cmd + opt + ⏻ rather than ⏏.

Comment: @nohillside - I'd forgotten Apple added Bluetooth to a perfectly good €40 keyboard & charged an extra €100 for the privilege ;) (We still have a houseful of the original wired versions)

Comment: @Tetsujin It's even worse. Until Apple fixes the Bluetooth issues in the M1 Mini (assuming it's fixeable via software) I enjoy a wired Bluetooth keyboard :-)

Comment: @birchlabs I am experiencing same problem too, did you found any way to fix this issue?

Comment: @musa still no fix!

Comment: I am experiencing exactly the same problem. Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: @Acimaz still no fix!

Comment: @Birchlabs I just made an update to 11.2.3 and that fixed it for me. Which version do you have?

Comment: @Acimaz I'm still on 11.2.2, so I'll be interested to try 11.2.3!

Comment: @Acimaz have tried sleep-by-keyboard twice so far on 11.2.3, and neither time did it present to me a lockscreen.

Comment: seems like 11.2.3 fixed the issue. I am testing and it's working right now.

Comment: no, still experiencing.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the settings got corrupted when upgrading to Big Sur.

- Open System Preferences -> Security & Privacy
- In the General tab, disable/untick "Require password after sleep"
- Quit System Preferences to have the changed settings written to disk
- Open the same panel again and enable the setting
- Quit System Preferences (and hope for the best)

Comment: Thanks @nohillside. this made it work twice in a row, but I've just now come back to find my computer unlocked, after a few hours away from it (I believe I put it to sleep prior to that). I think I'll need to continue monitoring the situation and work out whether there's any kind of pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same problem with sleep via hotkey not locking an iMac running Big Sur 11.5.2. Toggling the require password setting does not remedy the issue for me.
Until the bug is fixed I'm remapping my brain to use:
<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>